# Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted [docker]

Tags: docker, nginx, systemctl

I'm trying to create a docker image (centos7) with an nginx web server running on it. I have created a `Dockerfile` which looks like this:

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN yum update -y

# -------- OPENSSL -------- 

#ADD install-openssl.sh /
#RUN chmod +x install-openssl.sh
#RUN /install-openssl.sh

# -------- NGINX --------

RUN yum install epel-release -y
RUN yum install nginx -y

# Copy a configuration file from the current directory 
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# Append "daemon off:" to the beginning of the configuration
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80

RUN systemctl start nginx
```

I build my docker image with the following command:

```
docker build -t nginx-img .
```

And I run it like this:

```
docker -v run --name nginx-cont -p 80:80 -i  nginx-img
```

But I get the following error:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: You basically can't use `systemctl` (or `service` or init scripts) in Docker at all.  Make your image's `CMD` run the program you're trying to run as a foreground process: `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`.

Answer (score -2):

You need the [centos7 systemd image](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/) to run systemctl inside your container

Once you have the image ,

**change** :

`From centos:centos7 line in the dockerfile`

**to**

`From <new image name>`

that's it and you'll be good to go

**OR**

You can directly use the [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) image for the server